# Algorithm -- Finding the average of numbers in a circular buffer?

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm trying to think of an algorithm to keep track of the average of the numbers in a circular buffer, assuming numbers are overwritten as the buffer approaches capacity.

```
e.g. size = 4 
[1,2,7,3] => avg = 13/4 = 3.25
add(5)
[5,2,7,3] => avg = 17/4 = 4.25
```

Here's my current approach.

```
class CircularBuffer {

    int[] buffer;  
    int head;
    int tail;
    int sum;

    public CircularBuffer(int n) {   
        tail = 0;
        head = 0;
        buffer = new int[n];
    }

    void addNumber(int number) {  
        if (head == tail - 1) {
            sum -= buffer[tail - 1];
        } else if (head != tail - 1) {
            buffer[head++]= number;
            sum += number;
        }

        head = head % buffer.length;                 
    }

    double avg() {        
        if (head > vtail) {
            return sum / (head - tail + 1);
        } else { 
            return sum / buffer.length;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CircularBuffer buf = new CircularBuffer(3);
        buf.addNumber(1);
        buf.addNumber(2);
        buf.addNumber(3);
        buf.addNumber(4);
        System.out.println("Avg"+ buf.avg());                     
    }
```

What doesn't work: Currently returns 5 instead of 3.

Comment: Is there any problems with your code ? Some error, something unexpected ?

Comment: Your code formation is awful. Please take more care next time.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Added more detail. Basically Im trying to calculate the correct average when the buffer gets overwritten . Refer to comments in the code!

Comment: CircularBuffer [tail=0, sum=1, buffer=[1, 0, 0], head=1]
CircularBuffer [tail=0, sum=3, buffer=[1, 2, 0], head=2]
CircularBuffer [tail=0, sum=6, buffer=[1, 2, 3], head=0]
CircularBuffer [tail=0, sum=10, buffer=[4, 2, 3], head=1]
Avg5.0                                                                                                                              Running your program clearly shows your sum is incorrect. And your count of elements is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need the tail, you only need to know if you reached the length of the buffer, so the code looks something like this:

```
class CircularBuffer {

    int tail = 0;
    int head = 0;
    int[] buffer;
    int sum = 0;

    public CircularBuffer(int n) {
        buffer = new int[n];
    }

    void addNumber(int number) {
        sum -= buffer[head];
        sum += number;
        buffer[head++] = number;
        head = head % buffer.length;
        if (tail <= buffer.length) {
            tail++;
        }
    }

    double avg() {
        if (head == tail) {
            return (double) sum / (double) head;
        } else {
            return (double) sum / (double) buffer.length;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CircularBuffer buf = new CircularBuffer(3);
        buf.addNumber(1);
        buf.addNumber(2);
        buf.addNumber(3);
        buf.addNumber(4);
        System.out.println("Avg" + buf.avg());
    }
}
```

Since `buffer = new int[n];` fills the buffer with zeros, you don't need any if/else in method addnumber, you just substract the previous value and add the current. Hope it's clear.

Comment: One thing I would modify would be to check if `tail == buffer.length` (or really any int > buffer.length), don't increment.  That way `tail` doesn't increment indefinitely.  Although unlikely, `tail` could increment so much that it overflows and then eventually equals `head` again

Comment: @mstbaum - Thanks, I didn't thought of that, edited the code, show be ok now.

Comment: @Glissinda Can you explain how the average method works? I think there is a bug here . Consider the case when the buffer is not full.. `[1,2,0]`-> The average in this case should `1.5 (1+2)/2` and not `1. (1+2+0)/2`

Comment: @KodeSeeker there is if/else in method `avg`. In your case, the head will be same as tail, because the buffer is not full, so head is "2" and the average will be (1+2)/2

Answer (score 0):

Why can you just separate the average code vs the add code ?

Then you just have to traverse the array, sum it and divide it by the length.

Answer (score 0):

The `addNumber` method seems not to be working properly.

First, instead of simple `head == tail -1` you also need to consider case where `head==length-1 && tail==0` if you want to test if your buffer is full.

Second, if you buffer is full, you need to increase both head and tail. And you do that by `head = (head+1)%length` instead for simple `head++`, because `head` could have been `length-1`. Same for tail. Also, you forgot to add the number to the sum in this case, as well as actually insert the number into the backing array.

Comment: Thanks .. for pointing that out.. so would the code for average remain the same?

Comment: @kajacx OP does the modulus at the end of the `addNumber` function

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code somewhat.  Here's the main method, based on what you typed in your question.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    CircularBuffer buf = new CircularBuffer(4);
    buf.addNumber(1);
    buf.addNumber(2);
    buf.addNumber(7);
    buf.addNumber(3);
    System.out.println("Avg " + buf.avg());
    buf.addNumber(5);
    System.out.println("Avg " + buf.avg());
}
```

And here's the result when I ran the code.

```
Avg 3.25
Avg 4.25
```

Here's what I changed to get your code to first compile, then execute correctly.

1. I added a class declaration, and made all the variables class variables.
2. The head variable wasn't needed.  It's always the zero position.
3. I added a boolean to let me know when a value in the circular buffer was overwritten.
4. I initialized the sum and boolean variable bufferFull in the constructor.
5. I rewrote the addNumber method so that the sum would always contain the correct value.
6. Since sum always has the correct value, the avg method just calculates the average.
7. I formatted the Java code so it would be easier for others to read.

Here's the revised code.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

public class CircularBuffer {

    private boolean bufferFull;

    private int tail;
    private int sum;

    private int[] buffer;

    public CircularBuffer(int n) {
        this.bufferFull = false;
        this.tail = 0;
        this.sum = 0;
        this.buffer = new int[n];
    }

    public void addNumber(int number) {

        sum += number;
        if (bufferFull) {
            sum -= buffer[tail];
        }

        buffer[tail] = number;
        tail++;

        if (tail >= buffer.length) {
            tail = tail % buffer.length;
            bufferFull = true;
        }
    }

    public double avg() {

        int length = tail;
        if (bufferFull) {
            length = buffer.length;
        }
        return (double) sum / length;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CircularBuffer buf = new CircularBuffer(4);
        buf.addNumber(1);
        buf.addNumber(2);
        buf.addNumber(7);
        buf.addNumber(3);
        System.out.println("Avg " + buf.avg());
        buf.addNumber(5);
        System.out.println("Avg " + buf.avg());
    }
}
```

I hope you understand what I did and can apply these principles to your next assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation of the circular buffer which calculates sample mean and sample standard deviation when putting a new value into the buffer and getting the oldest value from the buffer.

I compare my results with ones from numpy.

Although this is implemented in Python, I hope this can help you on implementing the Java version.

Please let me know if any questions or suggestions.

```
import numpy as np
import math

# Circular Buffer
# Ref: https://embeddedartistry.com/blog/2017/05/17/creating-a-circular-buffer-in-c-and-c/

# Standard deviation calculated from sum, sum of squares.
# Ref: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/432256/how-would-i-calculate-the-standard-deviation-of-a-sample-given-the-sample-size

###############################################################################

class CircularBuffer:
    def __init__(self, buffer_size):

        if buffer_size <= 0:
            raise Exception('circular buffer : cannot initialize the circular buffer with zero or negative buffer size')

        self.buffer_size = buffer_size
        self.buffer = [0] * buffer_size
        self.head = 0
        self.tail = 0
        self.reset()

###############################################################################
def reset(self):
    self.head = self.tail
    self.full = False
    self.sum = 0
    self.sumsq = 0
    self.mean = 0
    self.stddev = 0

###############################################################################
def is_empty(self):
    return (not self.full and (self.head == self.tail))

###############################################################################
def is_full(self):
    return self.full

###############################################################################
def capacity(self):
    return self.buffer_size

###############################################################################
# return the number of using elements in the circular buffer.
# Because this is a circular buffer, not every element in the buffer counts.
def size(self):
    available_size = self.buffer_size
    if not self.full:
        if self.head >= self.tail:
            available_size = self.head - self.tail
        else: # can happen if using get()
            available_size = self.buffer_size + self.head - self.tail
    return available_size

###############################################################################
# put a new element at the head.
def put(self, item):
    # store the status before putting a new element
    replace_item = self.buffer[self.head]
    pre_head = self.head
    is_already_full = self.full

    # put a new element and update the status.
    self.buffer[self.head] = item
    if is_already_full:
        self.tail = (self.tail +1) % self.buffer_size
    self.head = (self.head + 1) % self.buffer_size
    self.full = (self.head == self.tail)

    # calculate sum, sumsq, mean, and stddev.
    stddev_square = 0
    current_size = self.size()
    if is_already_full:
        self.sum = self.sum - replace_item + self.buffer[pre_head]
        self.sumsq = self.sumsq - replace_item*replace_item + \
            self.buffer[pre_head] * self.buffer[pre_head]
    else:
        self.sum += item
        self.sumsq += (item*item)

    self.mean = self.sum / current_size
    if current_size > 1:
        denominator_one = 1 / (current_size - 1)
        denominator_two = 1 / (current_size*current_size - current_size)
        stddev_square = denominator_one * self.sumsq - denominator_two * self.sum * self.sum

    # handle rounding error.
    stddev_square = self.__verify_stddev_square(stddev_square)
    self.stddev = math.sqrt(stddev_square)

###############################################################################
# get the element at the tail
def get(self):
    if self.is_empty():
        return None

    # get the element at the tail
    item = self.buffer[self.tail]
    self.full = False
    self.tail = (self.tail + 1) % self.buffer_size

    # update sum, sumsq, mean, and stddev
    stddev_square = 0
    current_size = self.size()
    if current_size == 0:
        self.reset()
    else:
        self.sum -= item
        self.sumsq -= (item * item)
        self.mean = self.sum / current_size
        if current_size > 1:
            denominator_one = 1 / (current_size - 1)
            denominator_two = 1 / (current_size*current_size - current_size)
            stddev_square = denominator_one * self.sumsq - denominator_two * self.sum * self.sum

        stddev_square = self.__verify_stddev_square(stddev_square)
        self.stddev = math.sqrt(stddev_square)

    return item

###############################################################################
# handle the rounding error.
def __verify_stddev_square(self, stddev_square):
    if (stddev_square) < 0.0:
        stddev_square = 0
        current_size = self.size()
        for count in range(1,current_size+1):
            idx = (self.head - count) % current_size
            stddev_square += ((self.buffer[idx] - self.mean) * (self.buffer[idx] - self.mean))
        stddev_square /= (self.size() - 1)
    return stddev_square


###############################################################################

def test_circular_buffer():

    print('===== Test 00 =====')

    cb = CircularBuffer(10)
    for i in range(6):
        cb.put(i)
    numpyArray = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5])

    print('    cb full: {} vs False'.format(cb.is_full()))
    print('    cb size: {} vs. 6'.format(cb.size()))
    print('    cb mean: {} vs {}'.format(cb.mean, np.mean(numpyArray)))
    print('    cb std: {} vs {}'.format(cb.stddev, np.std(numpyArray, ddof=1)))
    # set ddof=1 for unbiased because we are working on sample, not population

    print('===== Test 01 =====')

    val = cb.get()
    numpyArray = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
    print('    cb full: {} vs False'.format(cb.is_full()))
    print('    cb size: {} vs. 5'.format(cb.size()))
    print('    cb mean: {} vs {}'.format(cb.mean, np.mean(numpyArray)))
    print('    cb std: {} vs {}'.format(cb.stddev, np.std(numpyArray, ddof=1)))

    print('===== Test 02 =====')

    cb.reset()
    for i in range(10):
        cb.put(i)
    numpyArray = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

    print('    cb full: {} vs True'.format(cb.is_full()))
    print('    cb size: {} vs. 10'.format(cb.size()))
    print('    cb mean: {} vs {}'.format(cb.mean, np.mean(numpyArray)))
    print('    cb std: {} vs {}'.format(cb.stddev, np.std(numpyArray, ddof=1)))

    print('===== Test 03 =====')

    cb = CircularBuffer(6)
    cb.put(1)
    cb.put(10)
    cb.put(82)
    cb.put(29)
    cb.put(33131)

    numpyArray = np.array([1, 10, 82, 29, 33131])
    print('    cb full: {} vs False'.format(cb.is_full()))
    print('    cb size: {} vs. 5'.format(cb.size()))
    print('    cb mean: {} vs {}'.format(cb.mean, np.mean(numpyArray)))
    print('    cb std: {} vs {}'.format(cb.stddev, np.std(numpyArray, ddof=1)))

    print('===== Test 04 =====')

    cb.put(64)
    numpyArray = np.array([1, 10, 82, 29, 33131, 64])

    print('    cb full: {} vs True'.format(cb.is_full()))
    print('    cb size: {} vs. 6'.format(cb.size()))
    print('    cb mean: {} vs {}'.format(cb.mean, np.mean(numpyArray)))
    print('    cb std: {} vs {}'.format(cb.stddev, np.std(numpyArray, ddof=1)))

    print('===== Test 05 =====')

    val = cb.get()
    val = cb.get()
    val = cb.get()
    val = cb.get()
    numpyArray = np.array([33131, 64])

    print('    cb full: {} vs False'.format(cb.is_full()))
    print('    cb size: {} vs. 2'.format(cb.size()))
    print('    cb mean: {} vs {}'.format(cb.mean, np.mean(numpyArray)))
    print('    cb std: {} vs {}'.format(cb.stddev, np.std(numpyArray, ddof=1)))

    print('===== Test 06 =====')

    cb = CircularBuffer(2)
    cb.put(103)
    cb.put(12)
    val = cb.get()
    val = cb.get()

    print('    cb full: {} vs False'.format(cb.is_full()))
    print('    cb size: {} vs. 0'.format(cb.size()))

    print('===== Test 07 =====')

    cb = CircularBuffer(2)
    cb.put(103)
    cb.put(12)
    val = cb.get()
    val = cb.get()
    cb.put(11)

    print('    cb full: {} vs False'.format(cb.is_full()))
    print('    cb size: {} vs. 1'.format(cb.size()))
    print('    cb mean: {} vs 11'.format(cb.mean))
    print('    cb std: {} vs 0'.format(cb.stddev))

    print('===== Test 08 =====')

    try:
        cb = CircularBuffer(-1)
    except Exception as e:
        print('    Catch the exception "{}" as expected'.format(e))

###############################################################################

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_circular_buffer()
    print('The End')
```